# How to force a trait to implement another traits

Tags: scala, multiple-inheritance, mixins, traits

I have three traits, I would like to force one of them call it `C` to mix in the traits `A` and `B`. I can't do it even though I know how to force `B` to mix in `A`. It could be done like this:

```
trait A {
  def getThree() = 3
}

trait B {
  this: A =>
  def getFive() = 2 + getThree()
}

trait C {
  this: A => // that's the line which 
  // this: B => // this line is incorrect as I there is "this: A =>" already
  // def getEight() = getThree() + getFive() // I want this line to compile
}
```

Thus I could call the function `getEight()`

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val b = new B with A {}
    println(b.getFive())

    // It would be cool to make these two lines work as well
    // val c = new C with B with A {}
    // println(c.getEight())    
  }
}
```

Comment: `this: A with B =>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `with`

```
trait C {
 self: A with B =>
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why did you use `self` instead of my `this`?

Comment: @GA1  `this` is used to refer to current object in context. used self just for the sake of clarity .

Comment: `this` should be used in this context, since there's no reason to introduce another self-type reference. Alternative self-type reference is used when you need to distinguish between different `this` instances, particularly in case of nested classes.